# TortoiseSVN - When I delete a folder I got trouble

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

A lot of times I need to delete a folder and copy another one with the same name. Always this is a place to trouble. What is the best way do do this?

The error I got when I trying to commit:

> ```
> Error: Directory    Error:
> '..\trunk\bin\MVCContrib\InputBuilderTemplates\.svn'
> Error: containing working copy admin
> area is missing   Error: Please
> execute the 'Cleanup' command.
> ```

The error I got when I trying to cleanup:

> ```
> '..\trunk\bin\MVCContrib\InputBuilderTemplates\.svn' is not a working copy directory.
> ```

Comment: Please tell us exactly what trouble you get, and exactly what steps you to through to get it.

Comment: @Close-voter:  Be sure to look at tags before closing :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. SVN Delete the folder
2. SVN Commit
3. SVN Rename, SVN Move or SVN Copy source folder to deleted folder name
4. SVN Commit